# Need Help Figuring Out Some clang-format Options

Tags: llvm-clang, clang-format

While using clang-format (8.0.0) I am encountering weird formatting issues that I feel may be bugs. I don't want to jump the gun and report them as bugs without knowing if I'm doing something incorrectly or missed a configuration setting though. I have a few examples of where I feel my settings are not being adhered to and instead the formatter is going 'rogue' in a sense.

Here is my .clang-format settings file:

```
---
Language: Cpp
# BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands: true
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: true
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeComma
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: true
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit: 0
CommentPragmas: '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks: Preserve
IncludeCategories: 
  - Regex: '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority: 2
  - Regex: '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority: 3
  - Regex: '.*'
    Priority: 1
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd: ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments: false
SortIncludes: false
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
...
```

**Example 1 - Single line assignments with multiple parentheses:**

Before formatting:

```cpp
extern "C"
{
    HBITMAP     (WINAPI *Real_LoadBitmapW)(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR) = LoadBitmapW;
    HANDLE      (WINAPI *Real_OpenMutexA)(DWORD, BOOL, LPCSTR) = OpenMutexA;
}
```

After formatting:

```cpp
    HBITMAP(WINAPI* Real_LoadBitmapW)
    (HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR) = LoadBitmapW;
    HANDLE(WINAPI* Real_OpenMutexA)
    (DWORD, BOOL, LPCSTR)                                                        = OpenMutexA;
```

Expected results:

```cpp
    HBITMAP (WINAPI* Real_LoadBitmapW)(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR)                                                                       = LoadBitmapW;
    HANDLE (WINAPI* Real_OpenMutexA)(DWORD, BOOL, LPCSTR)                                                                        = OpenMutexA;
```

Here, the formatter is randomly breaking my assignments into new lines as it sees fit. The ColumnWidth setting here appears to not be honored. If I set the ColumnWidth to an actual number, say 200, then the lines to not break, but the formatting is still incorrect as now space is placed after the return type. But using ColumnWidth breaks other formatting. I want to have ColumnWidth be set to 0 overall. I'm not sure what rule is forcing this to a new line and removing spaces after the return type.

---

**Example 2 - Not Honoring C-Style Casting Space Setting:**

Before formatting:

```cpp
    auto prodVer = (LPVOID)nullptr;
    auto prodVerSize = (UINT)0;
```

After formatting:

```cpp
    auto prodVer     = (LPVOID) nullptr;
    auto prodVerSize = (UINT)0;
```

Expected results:

```cpp
    auto prodVer     = (LPVOID)nullptr;
    auto prodVerSize = (UINT)0;
```

Here, a space is being added before the nullptr. This seems to only happen when using nullptr as the value being casted. If switched to a number or variable, it works fine. Also if switching the LPVOID to say, void*, it also fixes the issue. Also, with this issue, changing the 'Standard' setting from Cpp11 to Cpp03 fixes it as well but then introduces other formatting I do not want because of the standard changes. My code uses C++11,14,17,20 so using the Cpp11 Standard setting is needed here.

---

I just started using clang-format last night so I'm very new to this and trying to understand how the rules affect each other. I've read the docs page covering each rule and what it does, it just seems at certain times they are ignored like above.

I have other cases/issues, but I feel they may play into the above two. If I get these fixed first, the others may be fixed already as well so I can create another question later if more problems persist.

Comment: Using the https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator, I see these same issues on clang-format 6.0.0, and 10.0.0. So they've been there awhile and haven't been fixed. Both issues look like defects to me...